# Question regarding to iphone navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Good day everyone, currently I'm doing a simple project which uses the navigation controller default template.

Now I'm done with my current XIB (navigation template), I have created second XIB and I have added a navigation controller on it.

Let say:
It is a hierarchy table view, first the user choose one of the option available on the first table view, after that, will proceed to second XIB with another table view too.

My problem is, I have added one navigation button (Compose Email Item) on second XIB, but when I test run the program and reach second XIB, I couldn't see the button up there. Anyone know what happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code as to how you are adding the button and where you are placing that code.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have added a navigation controller in your second .XIB

But for second .XIB there is no need to add navigation controller, you just add UiViewController.

And in viewWillAppear method of second controller add your navigation button

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have added a navigation controller in second xib and added button on that. I think you have not done the connection in the second xib.